# Hector or CQL,Which one should i use

Tags: java, cassandra, hector, cql

I am new to cassandra. I have to write an application that uses  cassandra. I wanted to know which one will be  better for me so that i will not face much problem in future. Which api should i use for my application.

Comment: What kind of answer is that i am little bit confused so i am asking for help

Comment: You may want to read [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) as to why there are some close votes.  "Best" is a very subjective term, and it all really depends on what you need.

Comment: Please read the reason why this question was closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001328/which-one-is-the-best-client-api-hector-or-cql

Comment: I think this question is absolutely appropriate for SO.  Granted, it is a duplicate of the one mentioned above, but that one should not have been closed either.  I have flagged the earlier question as needing to be reopened, but this would have been closed anyway as a dup.

Comment: @edze: That isn't really a fair analogy.  Hector and CQL are both Cassandra clients supported by the same open source community  This (and the dup you pointed out) are really architectural questions rather than XY questions.

Comment: @ChrisGerken The first (unedited) question was, I know two APIs A and B which is the best 'A vs B'. Without any requirements and so on.

Comment: @edze: I understand and agree, it's just that this is a really important question to a lot of Cassandra users

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sunil, you're addressing a reasonable question, and I think it's wholly appropriate that you've asked it before coding away at a problem.  You might reach a more widely accepting audience if it were phrased something like, "What are the pros and cons I should look for between these two approaches to help me decide between them?"

The Hector client supports a programmatic interface for communicating with Cassanda, as well as a way to parse CQL statements, so your choice isn't necessarily between Hector and CQL, but more like programmatic vs. CQL, or a combination of the two.  You could face that same question even if choosing between Hector and Astyanax clients.

**Reasons to choose CQL:**

- CQL is easy to store, retrieve, and compare revisions.
- CQL is easy to read and reveiw, especially as DDL.
- CQL is easy to log for troubleshooting and auditing purposes.
- Developers with a history of RDBMS may acclimate more quickly to CQL, reducing training time or increasing a pool of candidates for hire.
- Community development is trending toward JDBC-like handling of CQL.

**Reasons to choose Programmatic:**

[AMENDMENT]

It appears some of my knowledge was outdated.  Based on jbellis' comment (*the* Jonathan Ellis, I presume), CQL is currently more performant than thrift, and also supports prepared statements.  I'm at a loss for a good argument against a CQL-based approach.

Comment: First Thanks for supporting this question.This answer is so useful for me

Comment: +1, but note that CQL has some defence against injection - See http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201107.mbox/%3C1309651952.2053.51.camel@erebus.lan%3E

Comment: @DNA, it's easy enough to inject, but I think its saving grace is that it's more likely to further constrain a search than to expand it.  Probably only a serious threat when it's in an exception table.  Other creative uses might exist, though.  In the example given, if getUser returned `"bob' AND password='1"`, it would be a valid injection, but might only give away in the error message what attributes are defined.  The word `password`, for example, could be substituted with `lname`, `income`, etc, and enough reasonable guesses could be used to map out parts of your schema.

Comment: Worth noting that CQL prepared statements are more performant than Thrift calls, so CQL wins on performance too.  (And of course using prepared statements is the way to protect against injection as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Another completely different option is playOrm so that you can do joins with no limitations.  playOrm allows you to do "scalable JQL" which looks like the below.  You only need to decide how to partition your data.

@NoSqlQuery(name="findJoinOnNullPartition", query="PARTITIONS t(:partId) select t FROM TABLE as t INNER JOIN t.security as s where s.securityType = :type and t.numShares = :shares")